# Print results of Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering if someone could help me or point me to a tutorial to help me understand how to send the results of a rails query into a view? At the moment, I am only able to run a query using the console, but I'm not sure how to render the results into a view. For example, I have a model called City with the attributes state, population_size, and capital. For example, if I run a query in the console:

```
results = City.where(:state => 'Virginia')
```

How can I run that same query in Rails? Specifically, where would I place that code? Sorry for the noob question, but I can't find any guides that explicitly show me how to do this. I have only found guides on how to work in the console, but now how to actually render a view of the results...

Thanks!!

Comment: Read the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Work through a whole tutorial to get started. That will teach you what you're asking here, plus a whole lot more basic stuff. I used this one: http://railsinstallfest.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the instance var to use it in your views

```
@results = City.where(:state => 'Virginia')
```

Now in your view you have access to @results

Answer (score 0):

You can create the instance var to access it throughout the request.

if you want an array of results.

```
 @results = City.where(:state => 'stateName')
```

if you want a single object

```
 @result = City.find_by(state: 'stateName', id: :id)
```

Both can help you in different circumstances.
Now in your view you have access to @results